# Anchor link goes too low

Tags: html, wordpress, hyperlink, anchor

First of all, my website is: www.interlaser.webovo.nl

The problem is the anchor links. If you click on "Lasershow" or "Over Interlaser" in the menu, the page goes a bit too low. The space between the menu and the header has to be atleast some pixels.

What i've tried:

- make a div between them. But then the colour of the different sections is a problem.
- Margin-top > doesnt help

Someone can tell what i did wrong?

Comment: [Please read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and also take a tour of the help centre to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you want us to visit your site, figure out where it's going wrong though possibly hundreds of lines of code, css html etc, copy/paste the code and hopefully it will work? I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

on each anchor element ( h2 for exemple ), adjust your height with margin and counterbalance with padding :

```
  padding-top: 40px;
  margin-top: -40px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use padding-top, rather than margin-top. Padding is considered to be part of the element, and is always preserved.